# Non-sequential Primary Key performance in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, performance, primary-key

Due to requirement to support distributed environment, each of my clients has been assigned unique node id, it appends the node id with running number as primary key and stores at local database. E.g.

> Client A node id = 200, first row in a table will have primary key
>   200,000
>
> Client B node id = 100, first row in a table will have primary key
>   100,000

These records then replicate to centralized database. Since primary key at centralized database is not in sequence, will it cause any serious **performance** issue when data size getting bigger?

Possible sequence of inserting new data at centralized database:

```
200,000
100,000
100,001
200,001
300,000
100,002
```

This may cause a big performance in SQL Server with table is clustered along the PK. However, will this happens in PostgreSQL 9.3?

Notes:

1. I can't use composite keys as it does not play well at my presentation layers.
2. The 3 digits running number is just a simplified example, real
   running number will be much bigger and sufficient.

Comment: Well, it pretty much depends on the queries you use to access the data, but I would not expect any performance hit.  I think the only place where you can see some difference is the index of the PK itself, inserting new rows will happen all over the place, not just one end (well, this is a somewhat naive interpretation, I admit).  I hope you devised a solution to avoid collision and overflow on these IDs ;)

Comment: Since you are only reserving 3 digits for use by each client, it is hard to see how the data size can get much bigger anyway.

Comment: @jjanes It it just a simplified example, real running number will be much bigger and sufficient.

Comment: Performance is a game of details.  Simplified examples don't work very well, unless you simplify exactly the right thing in the right way.  How far can you go without overflowing int?  Or are you using bigint, or numeric, or varchar/text which just hold a string of digits?  Most important, how many clients do you anticipate having?

Comment: @jjanes Noted. I will use bigint. Number of my clients is from range 200 to 3000. My main concern is will I get the same SQL Server clustered PK problem in PG 9.3?

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 solutions for you:

## Direct reference of sequence and using concat

One possible solution is to reference the seqence in insert statement directly and prepend your node-id. A similar question including answer you can find here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925601/4206293

## Using a UUID

Another possible solution is, if you don't need you node-id in the primary-key field, you can use the uuid-ossp extension which provides the type uuid and the functions to generate uuids: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/uuid-ossp.html

#### Use a trigger for these solutions

For both solutions: you can use a trigger to set the primary key.

Example:

```
-- table
CREATE TABLE test(
   id character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  "name" character varying,
   CONSTRAINT idx_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- seqence
CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;

-- Create Function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_trigger() 
RETURNS TRIGGER    
AS $$
BEGIN
   NEW.id := '100' || nextval('test_seq')::TEXT;
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-- add Trigger
CREATE TRIGGER insert_table_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON pkTable
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_trigger();
```

If you now insert a value in the table

```
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('test text');
```

you get your primary key '1001'

## Using MINVALUE and MAXVALUE

Another way is you use the MINVALUE and MAXVALUE of SEQUENCE to define an numeric space:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE node100_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 100000000000
  MAXVALUE 100999999999
  START 100000000000
  CACHE 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE node200_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 200000000000
  MAXVALUE 200999999999
  START 200000000000
  CACHE 1;
```

Comment: +1 on the UUID, but *don't* use a trigger. A function as column default is simpler, faster and safer. Also, you might want to mention `bigint` as intermediary option between `int` and `uuid`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, my concern is about *performance* of inserting non-sequential primary key at my *centralized database*. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @CKLee have you seen my comment above?

Comment: @dezso, I was told inserting non-sequential/random PK has big performance issue compare to sequential PK, is it true? BTW, by following Christopher's solution shall be able to avoid collision and overflow issues.

Comment: Your IDs do not like random at all.  To repeat myself, I'd expect a difference only in adding the new IDs to the index - page splits and reordering would happen more often than in a sequential PK.  But this is what happens with an average non-PK index anyway, so it must not be that terrible.  (In SQL Server, for example, when the table is clustered along the PK, the picture would be very different.)  Which part of the suggestion do you mean, by the way?  UUIDs are not better in this regard.

Comment: Sequentialness matters a lot less with SSDs too...some of the old best practices behavior with CI keys is out the window there.

Comment: @dezso The person told me was using clustered index in SQL Server as an example. However, I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 as my centralized database, where it seems pgsql does not have clustered index concept. I will add more node ids, whenever there is a new client (business grow). Do you have experience with pgsql on this matter? BTW, UUID will not be my first choice.

Answer (score 1):

Resurrection!!
This is an old thread and I think the same question and problem still exists more now since people have all kinds of distributed systems. Regarding the approach shown in the question, my 2c on this:

```
200,000
100,000
100,001
200,001
300,000
100,002
```

This is exactly what I was thinking a day earlier because I have the exact same problem. But even if I dont see it as a db perf issue there is stll a logical limit and assumption that records in first source will not exceed a Million. ( I was having a larger number like 20M in mind)

So while looking around I found this [very old PG forum thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4CB91515.6020201%40postnewspapers.com.au) and I like the suffix approach more than the prefix so the new ids look like for node1:

```
101
201
301
```

and for node 2

```
102
202
302
```

This gives you possible 100 nodes (you can always use 001,002 suffix for 1000 nodes).

- Pros:

  - Very simple solution, less gaps with PK index
  - Can be adjusted to add any number of nodes
- Cons:

  - This requires transformation when bringing data to central nodes
  - I am not much in favour of using some function to generate such PKs

But in our case since we do have other transformation rules- I think we can handle this.

Answer (score -3):

You can  create a sequence and make it global. Like below:

```
  create sequence seq;
```

Create a view on this sequence:

```
  CREATE VIEW seq_view AS SELECT nextval(‘seq’) as a;
```

Now, We will be using a foreign data wrapper to access the sequence:

```
  CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
  CREATE SERVER global_seq FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS(host 
 ‘192.168.XX.XX’, port ‘5432’, dbname ‘mydatabase’);
  CREATE USER MAPPING FOR PUBLIC SERVER global_seq OPTIONS (user ‘User’ , 
  password ‘xxxx’);
  CREATE FOREIGN TABLE seqtable (a bigint) SERVER global_seq OPTIONS ( 
  table_name ‘seq_view’);
```

Now, you can create a function like below to access the sequence for each insert:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func()
   RETURNS bigint
   LANGUAGE plpgsql
   SECURITY DEFINER
   AS $function$
   declare b bigint;
   BEGIN
   b := (select * from seqtable);
   RETURN b;
   end;
   $function$;
```

Now, attach the function with table:

```
   Create table mytab(
   col1 int8 not null default func(),
   col2 int2
   );
```

Same steps you can follow with other table and use the common sequence with them.

For detailed and more information refer by post: https://medium.com/@shishulkargini/postgres-make-your-sequence-global-a80924a81e29

Comment: Could you include the salient points from your blog into the answer itself? Otherwise it won't be very useful when the external link goes stale.

Comment: @Shiwangini - you should divulge your relationship to the blog post when you provide links in an answer, otherwise this starts to look like spam.

Comment: @mustaccio - I have edited my answer